# how a datepicker chooses the month selected from dropdownlist

Tags: php, javascript, html, datepicker

Snippet of html code

```
<li>
    <select name="months" class="sel">
        <option selected="" value="Default"> Month </option>
        <option value="Jan">January</option>
        <option value="Feb">February</option>
        <option value="Mar">March</option>
        <option value="Apr">April</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="Jun">June</option>
        <option value="Jul">July</option>
        <option value="Aug">August</option>
        <option value="Sep">September</option>
        <option value="Oct">October</option>
        <option value="Nov">November</option>
        <option value="Dec">December</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li><label class="label">From:</label></li>
<li><input name="fdate" type="text" class="sel" size="10"  id="SelectedDate"  
   readonly onClick="GetDate(this);"><li>
```

The problem here is the selected month from dropdown list should be shown in datepicker....

how to integrate this selected option to my datepicker code.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. If u using jQuery then no need to put separate listbox.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmanakumar/zd39M/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-start-custom-1.10.3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-datepicker-next, .ui-datepicker-prev { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-custom-1.10.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "-0:c+10",
                dateFormat: "dd - M - yy",
                onClose: function(selectedDate) {
                    $('#datepicker1').datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
            $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());

            $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
                yearRange: "-0:+0",
                dateFormat: "dd - M - yy"
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
        <input type="text" id="datepicker1" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

See [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) for reference

Comment: but i need previous days...also to be in active

Comment: then dont use `minDate: 0`

Comment: U want previous date or not? Or what exactly u want ?

Comment: k i got it.. but it is not working for another field in my requirement i.e., in my requirement there is from date and to date it is working for from date but not for to date field

Comment: ok now what i need is the functionality for two fields though am changing the id also it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
Or how do you mean, Cant really figure out what you want

**EDIT:****Try This**

If this is not what you are looking for i do not know what you want:

```
<?php
  $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date1", true);
  $myCalendar->setIcon("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
  $myCalendar->setDate(01, 03, 1960);
  $myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");
  $myCalendar->setYearInterval(1960, 2015);
  $myCalendar->dateAllow('1960-01-01', '2015-03-01');
  $myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-04-01", "2011-04-13", "2011-04-25"), 0, 'month');
  $myCalendar->setOnChange("myChanged('test')");
  $myCalendar->writeScript();
  ?>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script language="javascript">
```

`<!--
function myChanged(v){
    alert("Hello, value has been changed : "+document.getElementById("date1").value+"["+v+"]");
}
//-->
</script>`

Comment: no what i mean is if i select a month in above dropdownlist then in my input datepicker tag it have to show that month dates

Comment: Oow like that sorry did not know what you wanted execly

Comment: Ok then im afraid ik cant help you.

Comment: But i found i really easy so you did not really search for it

Comment: no! what my question mean is...? if i select month in dropdownlist for eg... i selected april... now the datepicker should show april month calender....

Comment: Thats execly what the datepicker in the link does.

Comment: Yeah its showing the month that it is, That also why there is a today button

Comment: no ..... we have to select the month seperately using select tag not in that datepicker...

Comment: no yaar...?listen actually i have to select jus month from above dropdownlist(select tag) k then that selected month should be displayed by the datepicker...

Comment: I dont even think that what you want is possible

Comment: Please look ad my edit I've found something and i think its what you are looking for

Comment: where is the class tc_calender code? what should i place in it..?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/5jWTR/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

Comment: k this is enough for me but how can i restrict not to display before year values like <2013...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        });
});
```